# h2o version vs h2o R version conflict

Tags: r, h2o

Quite new to h2o. I updated my h2o-R package to 3.26 and I also installed the h2o cluster one by running

- `java -jar h2o.jar`'

After running both and the h2o flow was accessible on the browser, when I run h2o.init(), it's still telling me that my h2o cluster is at 3.24 and h2o-R package is at 3.26.

Do I need to remove a previous h2o.jar version? How would I go about doing that?

I have forced it to work by initializing h2o by having the strict version check be false but, I want both h2o and h2o-R to be on the same version.

Thanks a lot!

Zarni

P.S. I have attached screenshots of the errors.

***h2o.init() Error!***
[image]

***.jar run 01***
[image]

***.jar run 02***
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cluster information printed shows that it's connecting to an H2O cluster (version 3.24.0.5) that was started 30 minutes ago (running at the default location, localhost:54321).  You will need to shut that one down first (kill the java process from the command line or simply, `h2o.shutdown()`.

You don't need to remove or uninstall anything, you just need to kill the active (old) cluster.  After that, start from R using `h2o.init()` and it will use the updated version.

Comment: Hi @Erin LeDell, I just re-did h2o.shotdown() and re-run h2o.init() from the R Console and it's still using the old version. Is there a way I can check the updated version is installed? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @Erin LeDell, I have resolved the issue. I asked my IT to uninstall my Java Run Time environment, re-install then, run the .jar for h2o and it works. Might have been permission issues since IT has administrative rights (Not sure though).
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @Erin LeDell, Turned out the issue props again after I restarted my AWS instance. I am not back to h2o version 3.24.0.5. Do you think it's possibly a systems configuration level issue?
Thanks,
Zarni

Comment: @Zami If there's an older H2O cluster that's running, then you'll have to kill it (but I don't know why this would restart automatically after restarting your AWS instance)?